# The Board Football Problem (Probability)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

A and B are playing " board football", a two player in which the objective is to score as many goals as possible. As the game does not have any terminating statement, an infinite number of rounds are played.(Similar to having an infinitely large board of Scrabble with infinite number of tiles,for example [www.babbl.xyz](http://www.babbl.xyz))

The rules are as follows:

**1**)*The player with the ball(say A) has to make a certain number of "passes" before they get to shoot. The player in possession (here A) has to roll an n-sided dice, and the number that turns up is the number of passes they make within that round, **unless they are intercepted**.*

**2**)*If the other player/the defender(say  B) rolls the dice and gets the same number, then an 'interception'  takes place and now B is in possession of the ball and the game continues.* **(Note that the a round is said to have been completed when the attacker and the defender both have rolled the dice(s).)**

**3**)*If the player in possession manages to complete/achieve the required number of passes, they have the opportunity to shoot. This can be done in multiple ways. For example, if the number of required passes are 8 and one six sided dice is being used, then the attacker can reach this number by rolling 2-3-2-1 , 6-2 , 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 and so on.*

**4**)*The number of passes made by the player in possession can be higher than the required number of passes.For example if the number of required passes are 8 and one six sided dice is being used, then the attacker can reach this number by rolling 6-6 as well.*

**5**)*For determining the result of the shot, a coin is tossed. If it lands as heads, the player who is shooting scores but if it lands tails, then the other player controls the ball and the game continues.The coin tossing takes place in the same round in which the completing pass was made and in both cases, the other player is in possession of the ball when the game restarts.*

> For example, let one 6 sided dice be used and the required number of
> passes be 9.
> (That is n=6, m=1,p=9) Let us say that A has the ball in the starting.
>
> - In the first round, A rolls 4 and B rolls 5. A completes 4 passes within that round.A now has to complete at least 5 more passes in order to get an opportunity to shoot.
> - In the second round, A rolls 3 and B rolls 3. Possession is overturned and now B controls the ball.B now has 0 passes completed.
> - In the third round, B rolls 5 and A rolls 2.B has completed 5 passes in this round and needs to complete at least 4 more passes in order to get an opportunity to shoot.
> - In the fourth round, B rolls 6 and A rolls 4. **Although B has overshot the number of passes, due to *Rule 4*,  B is permitted to flip the coin (B however will not be allowed to proceed in this case when question (7) and (8) are being considered.** B tosses the coin and gets heads. B scores a goal.B leads by one goal to nil. Now A starts
>   off with possession of the ball.

Now, let p= number of required passes and n=sides of the dice, m= number of dices being used and z=number of goals required to have been scored. Then;

1. What is the probability that the player in possession scores without being intercepted?
2. Let both the players use 'm' dice each instead of one. What is the new probability that the player in possession scores without being intercepted? (Here, an interception is only valid if the sum of the numbers obtained by the defender is equal to the sum obtained by the attacker)
3. What is the minimum
   number of rounds that need to be completed such that the probability of at least one goal having been scored in the game is maximum? (for any given value of n and p)
4. (3) but now both the players have 'm' dice.
5. (3) but with at least 'z' goals having been scored.
6. (4) but with at least 'z' goals having been scored.
7. Assume Rule 4 is invalid ie.the player in possession must keep rolling until the desired number is obtained to make the number of passes made exactly equal to the number of required passes. Now find out the answers for (1),(2),(3),(4),(5) and (6) .
8. Assume Rule 4 is invalid ie. If the player in possession rolls a number that overshoots the required number of passes, then the possession shifts over to the other player. Now find out the answers for (1),(2),(3),(4),(5) and (6) .

Is there any way to solve this question with its generalizations? If yes, how and are there any unique answers? If not, how would one solve for say n=12, m=3 , p=71 and z=5 without plugging in values/ brute force?
I understand that is a very long drawn-out question so I'll be grateful to any contributions made.

*PS This isn't a homework question/problem so please don't close it because an answer is being requested. It is an original question. Consider this to be a challenge of sorts.*

*PPS The question has now been segmented. I'll leave this one on as it is the most comprehensive one.*

Part I:([The Board Football Problem (Part I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050959/the-board-football-problem-part-i))

Part II:([The Board Football Problem (Part II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050983/the-board-football-problem-part-ii))

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: @saulspatz Not very far. I thought I could analyse the cases formed for the simple scenarios (m=1, z=1) and maybe extrapolate from that, but the cases blow up too fast. It's highly likely that I'm not as well versed in probability theory as the question demands me to be, so I could be missing something obvious. Maybe when I have time I'll try to code this in and check the cases.

Comment: The many details of the question make it unappealing to those not concerned with the game.  It would not be hard to simulate, but an analytic solution seems difficult because it involves a lot of casework.  I would be surprised if it gets an answer unless we have someone who has already made a simulation.

Comment: @RossMillikan I agree. Would it make sense to shift this question to maybe MathOverflow as the users over there may be more inclined towards such problems? I'm not aware of any forums that deal with math puzzles.

Comment: No, MathOverflow is for professional researchers in math.  There is no glory in solving a problem as specific as this unless it is related to many problems of interest to the community. Many of them could do it, as could many of the people here, but it is too much detail to interest them.  If you look at the problems that do get answered, there is a lot of symmetry that makes general approaches work.  This one has too many details for that.

Comment: Hm. So a dead end?

Comment: Unless your problem can interest other people, you have the usual choices of learning enough to solve it yourself or hiring someone to solve it for you.  I haven't read it carefully enough to really say, but there are many questions here.  If you want an environment that can answer them all, and it looks like you want one that can answer many more that are similar, it would take me some weeks to have an answer.  Some people may have tools already developed that make it *much* faster, but there aren't too many of them.

Comment: I agree with the ideas expressed so far.  I also was *turned off* by the complexity of the query.  Perhaps you could post a separate query.  In this separate query, you might feature a question that takes 1 or 2 paragraphs to explain, along with what you have tried.  While this might require that you narrow your focus to only one aspect of the query, and perhaps oversimplify the question that you are asking, you'll probably get good mathSE responses.  Then, you could post a followup question as a separate new query, perhaps having the new query include a link to the old one, for background.

Comment: @user2661923 So should I take down this question and post segments of this question? I didn't want to do that because I feared that the question would lose its essence by simplification. I personally don't think the question is tough to understand. Calculating is a different thing...

Comment: "I feared that the question would lose its essence by simplification. I personally don't think the question is tough to understand."  Good points.  I do **not** advise deleting the question.  Wait 72 hours.  Then, if you haven't gotten the responses that you want, don't touch **this** question, simply then follow my suggestion, trying to minimize *oversimplification errors*.  What else can you do?

Comment: @user2661923 I have made some changes.

Comment: I just don't have the energy for this.  Send me a flagging comment in three days, when you execute plan B.

Comment: For any fixed parameters, this game is simply a probabilistic finite-state machine, whose transition matrix can be written down and the relevant probabilities (of $A$ or $B$ scoring the next goal) calculated via linear algebra.

Comment: I am working on most of an answer to at least question #1 Some questions in the meantime: 
A. Is question #1 intended to be the chance that player in possession scores  before the other player does, *allowing* possession to change back and forth (by interceptions or failed chances to score)? Or is it asking the chance to score before possession changes at all?
B. How do interceptions work if $m>1$? Does the other player roll a single die to match any of the $m$ dice? Do both roll $m$ dice and any of the $m^2$ pairs matching counts? Do both roll $m$ labeled dice and a labeled pair must match?

Comment: @MarkS. (1) Is for the probability that a player scores without being intercepted /change of possession. Which means that it does not matter who scores first, only the probability of the player scoring without being interrupted is required.For "m" dice, only when the sum of the numbers that the defender obtains in that round equals to that of the attacker, does an interception take place.Consider that both players have m dice.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. If your questions 5 and 6 are *also* intended to be without a change in possession, then it appears at first glance that, for the purposes of the mathematics, all discussion of a change in possession could just be changed with "the game ends" (maybe with a caveat that this is different than real games of board football).

Comment: Actually, my previous comment doesn't make sense given that possession changes even when someone scores once, so 5 and 6 must allow changes in possession.

Comment: @user2661923 Changes have been made.

Comment: @Ross Millikan It turns out that question #1 (split off into [its own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4050959/26369) now) admits a relatively nice analytic solution, especially approximately as $p$ grows large.